# Obtaining a collection of constructed subclassed types using reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

I want to create a class which implements IEnumerable<T> but, using reflection,  generates T's and returns them via IEnumerable<T>, where T' is a entirely constructed subclass of T with some properties hidden and others read-only.

Okay., that might not be very clear. Let me explain this via the medium of code - I'd like to have a class CollectionView<T> as follows:-

```
public class CollectionView<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
  public CollectionView(IEnumerable<T> inputCollection, 
    List<string> hiddenProperties, List<string> readonlyProperties) {
    // ...
  }

  // IEnumerable<T> implementation which returns a collection of T' where T':T.
}

...

public class SomeObject {
  public A { get; set; }
  public B { get; set; }
  public C { get; set; }
}

...

var hiddenProperties   = new List<string>(new[] { "A" });
var readOnlyProperties = new List<string>(new[] { "C" });

IEnumerable<SomeObject> someObjects = CollectionView<SomeObject>(hiddenProperties,
  readOnlyProperties);

...

dataGridView1.DataSource = someObjects;
```

(When displayed in dataGridView1 shows columns B and C and C has an underlying store which is read-only)

Is this possible/desirable or have I completely lost my mind/does this question demonstrate my deep inadequacy as a programmer?

I want to do this so I can manipulate a collection that is to be passed into a DataGridView, *without having to directly manipulate the DataGridView to hide columns/make columns read-only*. So no 'oh just use dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(blah) / dataGridView1.Columns[blah].ReadOnly = true' answers please!!

Help!

Answer (score 1):

[Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) will help you accomplish this. 
What you would do is create an interceptor that inherits T. You would store the collection of hidden and read-only properties. When a getter or setter is called, the interceptor would check to see if the property exists in either collection and then take appropriate action.

However, I know not how you would hide a property. You cannot change the access modifier of a base class in a derived class. You MAY be able to use the `new` keyword, but I know not how to do that with Castle.DynamicProxy.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't hide properties, even by creating subclassed proxies. You could at least construct a different type dynamically, which holds good properties, but it would not be a `T`.

But returning an object list could be sufficient if you just need to use databinding.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a different approach to this problem, I really wasn't seeing the wood for the trees! I decided to create an extension method which converts my IEnumerable to a data table which can then be passed around as required:-

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    DataTable ret = new DataTable();

    Type type = typeof(T);

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        // Ignore indexed properties.
        if (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0) continue;
        ret.Columns.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
    }

    foreach (T data in collection)
    {
        DataRow row = ret.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            // Ignore indexed properties.
            if (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0) continue;

            row[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(data, null);
        }

        ret.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ICustomTypeDescriptor to filter the property list.  To do this, I created a wrapper class for the data object (MyWrapper), a custom property descriptor (MypropertyDescriptor), and the collection class.  I extended the collection class to also observe IList so the data can be modified, and ITypedList so that the datagrid can build the columns.  You might also want to inherit ObservableCollection<> or BindingList<>.

The custom descriptor is to handle setting and retrieving the property value:

```
public sealed class MyPropertyDescriptor : System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor
{
    private PropertyDescriptor innerProperty;
    private Boolean isReadonly;

    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor innerProperty, Boolean isReadonly)
        : base(innerProperty.Name, GetAttributeArray(innerProperty.Attributes))
    {
        this.innerProperty = innerProperty;
        this.isReadonly = isReadonly;
        if (!isReadonly) this.isReadonly = innerProperty.IsReadOnly;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return this.innerProperty.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override Boolean IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.isReadonly; }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this.innerProperty.PropertyType; }
    }
    public override String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innerProperty.Name;
        }
    }
    public override String DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innerProperty.DisplayName;
        }
    }
    public override Boolean SupportsChangeEvents
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override void SetValue(Object component, Object value)
    {
        if (!this.isReadonly)
        {
            this.innerProperty.SetValue(component, value);
            if (component is MyWrapper) (component as MyWrapper).NotifyPropertyChanged(this.innerProperty.Name);
        }
    }
    public override Object GetValue(Object component)
    {
        return this.innerProperty.GetValue(component);
    }

    public override Boolean CanResetValue(Object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public override void ResetValue(Object component)
    {
    }
    public override Boolean ShouldSerializeValue(Object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static Attribute[] GetAttributeArray(AttributeCollection attributes)
    {
        List<Attribute> attr = new List<Attribute>();
        foreach (Attribute a in attributes) attr.Add(a);

        return attr.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The wrapper class is to control access to the properties via ICustomTypeDescriptor:

```
public sealed class MyWrapper : System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Object innerObject;
    private String[] hiddenProps;
    private String[] readonlyProps;

    private Type innerType;

    public MyWrapper(Object innerObject, String[] hiddenProps, String[] readonlyProps)
        : base()
    {
        this.innerObject = innerObject;
        this.hiddenProps = hiddenProps;
        this.readonlyProps = readonlyProps;
        this.innerType = innerObject.GetType();
    }

    public static PropertyDescriptorCollection FilterProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc, String[] hiddenProps, String[] readonlyProps)
    {
        List<PropertyDescriptor> list = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in pdc)
        {
            if (hiddenProps != null)
            {
                Boolean isHidden = false;
                foreach (String hidden in hiddenProps)
                {
                    if (hidden.Equals(pd.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        isHidden = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isHidden) continue; // skip hidden
            }

            Boolean isReadonly = false;
            if (readonlyProps != null)
            {
                foreach (String rp in readonlyProps)
                {
                    if (rp.Equals(pd.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        isReadonly = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            list.Add(new MyPropertyDescriptor(pd, isReadonly));
        }

        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(list.ToArray());
    }

    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor Members

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return FilterProperties(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.innerType, attributes), hiddenProps, readonlyProps);
    }
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        return FilterProperties(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.innerType), hiddenProps, readonlyProps);
    }

    AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this.innerType);
    }

    String ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this.GetType());
    }
    String ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this.GetType());
    }
    TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.GetType());
    }
    EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this.GetType());
    }
    PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }
    Object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this.GetType(), editorBaseType);
    }
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return null;
    }
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return null;
    }

    Object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this.innerObject;
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.propertyChanged != null) this.propertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { propertyChanged += value; }
        remove { propertyChanged -= value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the modified version of your CollectionView<>.  The bulk of this sample just maps the interface methods to the inner list.

```
public sealed class CollectionView<T> : IEnumerable<MyWrapper>, System.Collections.IList, IList<MyWrapper>, ITypedList
{
    private String[] hiddenProps;
    private String[] readonlyProps;
    private List<MyWrapper> collection;

    public CollectionView(IEnumerable<T> innerCollection, String[] hiddenProps, String[] readonlyProps)
        : base()
    {
        this.hiddenProps = hiddenProps;
        this.readonlyProps = readonlyProps;

        this.collection = new List<MyWrapper>();
        foreach (T item in innerCollection)
        {
            this.collection.Add(new MyWrapper(item, hiddenProps, readonlyProps));
        }
    }

    #region ITypedList Members

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return MyWrapper.FilterProperties(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)), this.hiddenProps, this.readonlyProps);
    }

    String ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<MyWrapper> Members

    IEnumerator<MyWrapper> IEnumerable<MyWrapper>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IList Members
    Int32 System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
    {
        return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).Add(value);
    }
    void System.Collections.IList.Clear()
    {
        (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).Clear();
    }
    Boolean System.Collections.IList.Contains(Object value)
    {
        return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).Contains(value);
    }
    Int32 System.Collections.IList.IndexOf(Object value)
    {
        return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).IndexOf(value);
    }
    void System.Collections.IList.Insert(Int32 index, Object value)
    {
        (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).Insert(index, value);
    }
    Boolean System.Collections.IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).IsFixedSize; }
    }
    Boolean System.Collections.IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).IsReadOnly; }
    }
    void System.Collections.IList.Remove(Object value)
    {
        (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).Remove(value);
    }
    void System.Collections.IList.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
    {
        (this.collection as System.Collections.IList).RemoveAt(index);
    }
    Object System.Collections.IList.this[Int32 index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.collection as System.Collections.IList)[index];
        }
        set
        {
            (this.collection as System.Collections.IList)[index] = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICollection Members
    void System.Collections.ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, Int32 index)
    {
        (this.collection as System.Collections.ICollection).CopyTo(array, index);
    }
    Int32 System.Collections.ICollection.Count
    {
        get { return (this.collection as System.Collections.ICollection).Count; }
    }
    Boolean System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return (this.collection as System.Collections.ICollection).IsSynchronized; }
    }
    Object System.Collections.ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return (this.collection as System.Collections.ICollection).SyncRoot; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList<MyWrapper> Members
    Int32 IList<MyWrapper>.IndexOf(MyWrapper item)
    {
        return this.collection.IndexOf(item);
    }
    void IList<MyWrapper>.Insert(Int32 index, MyWrapper item)
    {
        this.collection.Insert(index, item);
    }
    void IList<MyWrapper>.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
    {
        this.collection.RemoveAt(index);
    }
    MyWrapper IList<MyWrapper>.this[Int32 index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.collection[index];
        }
        set
        {
            this.collection[index] = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICollection<MyWrapper> Members
    void ICollection<MyWrapper>.Add(MyWrapper item)
    {
        this.collection.Add(item);
    }
    void ICollection<MyWrapper>.Clear()
    {
        this.collection.Clear();
    }
    Boolean ICollection<MyWrapper>.Contains(MyWrapper item)
    {
        return this.collection.Contains(item);
    }
    void ICollection<MyWrapper>.CopyTo(MyWrapper[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)
    {
        this.collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }
    Int32 ICollection<MyWrapper>.Count
    {
        get { return this.collection.Count; }
    }
    Boolean ICollection<MyWrapper>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    Boolean ICollection<MyWrapper>.Remove(MyWrapper item)
    {
        return this.collection.Remove(item);
    }
    #endregion
}
```